# On-chain or Off-chain: Optimal Calculation for Arbitraging Two v2 Pairs?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, etherscan, contract-invocation, arbitrage

I'm currently exploring arbitrage opportunities involving two v2 pairs and I'm wondering whether it's more advisable to compute the optimal amount to trade on-chain or off-chain. What are the key considerations and factors to weigh in making this decision?